# AJAX POST: header not going through

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, http-headers, web-development-server

I am trying to initiate an AJAX POST request and added some custom headers, but I am getting back invalid API KEY as a response from the server. I checked it at least a 100 time now and the API key and the API secret are the same as the one issued. I was thinking for some reason the header isn't going through correctly.

AJAX Resquest:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "https://api.coinigy.com/api/v1/exchanges",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type" : 'application/json',
                "X-API-KEY" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "X-API-SECRET" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
```

Response:

```
{"err_num":"1055-00-01","err_msg":"Invalid API Key"}
```

Request Headers from firefox:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-api-key,x-api-secret
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: api.coinigy.com
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
```

I truly dont know what I'm missing here. I used the same API key and secret for another call and that seems to work just fine.

Comment: Don't you get an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` related error on your console? The headers you're seeing are probably related to the `OPTIONS` request your browser does to check whether it can do the actual request.

Comment: No, I don't get any error, in fact, I get 200 exit code from the server. Its also being sent as an OPTIONS request instead of a POST.

Comment: Check this link it may help https://help.apiary.io/tools/browser-jsagent/

Comment: Actually, found a way around it, used the backend to send the request and return data. Thank you both for your help though.